# Get Excel tab colors to Treview node color - wrong colors displayed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vsto, excel-addins

I'm trying to get the tab colors of excel sheets to treeview nodes.backColor, but i'm not getting the correct colors and i'm not sure way (red is blue, blue is orange...). Please let me know what i'm doing wrong.

[image]

```
Sub sheets_loadToTreeView()
        Dim WB As Excel.Workbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook
        Dim SH As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim dSHeets As New Dictionary(Of String, String), dKey, tabColor
        Dim dColors As New Dictionary(Of String, Color)
        Dim mainNode As TreeNode, colorNode As TreeNode, shNode As TreeNode, MyNode1() As TreeNode
        Dim colorname As String

        For Each SH In WB.Worksheets
            tabColor = color_integerToColor(SH.Tab.Color)
            dSHeets.Add(SH.Name.ToString(), SH.Tab.Color)
            If Not dColors.ContainsKey(SH.Tab.Color) Then
                dColors.Add(SH.Tab.Color, tabColor)
            End If
        Next


        With Me.TreeView1
            .CheckBoxes = True
            .Nodes.Clear()

            mainNode = .Nodes.Add("sheets", "Sheets")

            For Each dKey In dColors.Keys
                colorName = "------------------"
                colorNode = mainNode.Nodes.Add(dKey, colorName)
                colorNode.Tag = "color"
                colorNode.BackColor = dColors(dKey)
                colorNode.ForeColor = dColors(dKey)
            Next

            For Each dKey In dSHeets.Keys
                MyNode1 = Me.TreeView1.Nodes.Find(dSHeets(dKey), True)

                If UBound(MyNode1) >= 0 Then
                    shNode = MyNode1(0).Nodes.Add(dKey, dKey)
                    shNode.Tag = "sheet"
                End If
            Next
            .ExpandAll()
            'MyNode.FirstNode.EnsureVisible()
        End With
    End Sub

    Public Function color_toInteger(ByVal C As Color) As Integer
        Return C.ToArgb
    End Function

    Public Function color_integerToColor(ByVal colorValue As Integer) As Color
        Return Color.FromArgb(colorValue)
    End Function
```

Comment: Maybe it's ARGB <-> BGRA?

Comment: I only have the options FromArgb, FromKnownColor, FromName

Comment: I'm saying that because if you invert the bytes representing Red `(255, 0, 0)`, you get Blue `(0, 0, 255)`. If you invert that light blue-ish color (similar to DodgerBlue `(30, 144, 255)`) you get Orange.

Comment: @Jimi any idea on how i can do this? Because all i'm doing is a direct sistem conversion so in my mind there is no reason it would be reversed. If there is an easier way i should do this please let me know

Comment: The first thing you have to do is to fix your code. You have a `dColors` which is declared  as `Dictionary(Of String, Color)`, but you're adding as Key `SH.Tab.Color` as it it was a string, the same value you're passing to `color_integerToColor()` which accepts an integer instead. I don't know what you're working with. -- I suggest you set `Option Strict ON` before anything else, so you at least will work with real Types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @jimi, I did have my variable type set incorrectly, but that was not the problem.
The problem was that Red and Blue were indeed reversed, so I needed the break down the color into RGB and then reverser the Blue and Red position.

```
    Public Function color_integerToColor(ByVal colorValue As Integer) As Color
        'Return Color.FromArgb(colorValue,)

        'SOURCE: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17432.vb-net-how-to-convert-a-32-bit-integer-into-a-color.aspx

        Dim Bytes As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(colorValue)
        Dim Alpha As Byte = Bytes(3)
        Dim Red As Byte = Bytes(0)   '2
        Dim Green As Byte = Bytes(1)
        Dim Blue As Byte = Bytes(2)  '0
        Return Color.FromArgb(Alpha, Red, Green, Blue)
    End Function
```